# What is the equivalent of Android's "html-textview" in Objective-C

Tags: android, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Getting HTML text from back-end, used uilabel for dynamic height with autolayout in uitableview, i am removing html tags, it is affecting the performance while scrolling and while opening the app it is taking more time.

Now i tried with uiwebview, tried code

```
dynamicWebview.delegate = self;
dynamicWebview.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
dynamicWebview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
heightConstraint.constant = dynamicWebview.scrollView.contentSize.height;
[dynamicWebview loadHTMLString:[syntable valueForKey:@"extraDesc"] baseURL:nil];
```

and in webviewdidfinishload

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
aWebView.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
aWebView.frame = frame;
}
```

but in this i am facing the dynamic height problem for the uiwebview and for the row height too, it is going out of the rowheight, after reloading the cell its getting fit. After trying this i am thinking uilabel only will be the best to acheive what am i trying.

I tried [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) and [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) RTLabel is supporting html tags but unable to use it in IB, TTTAttributedLabel is supporting IB but not the HTML Tags

In android to achieve this they are using a library called [html-textview](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview) it is dynamically adjusting and handling the html tags too.

Is there any other Objective c way to do that, if not; what should i use.

Edit: i have tried NSAttributedString too like below, this also affecting the performance much.

```
NSString *extraDesc = [syntable valueForKey:@"extraDesc"];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[extraDesc dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
splittext.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Use one Library called PTSMessenger cell...It will take care of all your dynamic cell height issues. I have used this library for my chatting app...its Awesome.

Comment: i downloaded that https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell/ it is throwing errors "messageSize:" method was not there in that tableviewcell.

Comment: +(CGRect)messageSize:(NSString*)message
{
    //    return [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([PTSMessagingCell maxTextWidth], CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    
    return [message boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([PTSMessagingCell maxTextWidth], CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageTextSize]}context:nil];
}

Comment: put this meathod in PTSMessenger cell.m   and declare this meathod in PTSMessenger cell.h file.

Comment: No known class method for selector 'maxTextWidth' i am getting this error in the above code.

Comment: +(CGFloat)maxTextWidth {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return 220.0f;
    } else {
        return 400.0f;
    }
}


Add this

Comment: still it is throwing many errors, can you sent me that updated library to my mail mohanramiosdev@gmail.com, thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158385/discussion-between-r-mohan-and-neeraj-sonaro).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
self.htmlLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: i tried this too, it is also not smooth as uiwebview or tttattributedlabel, forget to add in my question. will update now, thank you.